# Compatibility Problems & Limitations when bridging/interfacing Old ASP.NET Webforms/.NET Framework 4 w/ newer .NET Core Web API, MVC & Razor Pages?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-core, webforms, visual-studio-2019, .net-framework-version

At work, we have an Old application developed with the following technologies:

- Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate
- .NET Framework 4
- C# 4.0
- ASP.NET WebForms

With our application we are Highly concerned with issues like:

-security,

-links,

-and users sessions.

We have some new software requirements features which in turn means that we have to add to the existing application.

We would like to use newer Microsoft .NET  technologies for the new features.

However, we are concerned about compatibility problems.  We have Visual Studio 2019, and we would like to develop the new features using Visual Studio 2019.
But, how far can we go before we have compatibility problems, and face other kinds of limitations?
Is it possible to successfully bridge the Old application with newer technologies like:

-.NET Core Web API

-.NET Core MVC

-.NET Core Razor Pages?

Again, we can Not compromise on the following:

-security

-links

-and users sessions

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use both .net framework application and .net core application inside single hosted application. Same thing i have done in one of my project. old project was in .net framework 4.5 and we wanted to build new features in .net core with web api. 
We did and integrate both application inside a single application which is hosted on IIS server.

In term of security and sessions , .net core provide more control over these things.

Let me know if you need more help of info.

Comment: Thank you for responding.  Yes, may I please know if you searched & found any guides / tutorials / how-to on the internet that might give some explanation about said topic?

Comment: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/ go through this for razor pages...probably there is no such articles which exactly suit your requirement. i will recommend ..create a poc project in .net core and integrate with existing application. this will give you an idea how things are working and also build your confidence.